# Salesforce test class for controller

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have give two methods **selctedInvs** and **InvQtyChange** and skip other for simplicity. selctedInvs covered successfully the problem is to  cover InvQtyChange. In that **wrapInvList** receives 0 for Qty as that is set to 0 in selctedInvs but in visualforce page it changed dynamically that I can't do in test class.So for loop in InvQtyChange  is not covered. How to overcome this.

controller:

```
public class TrasferPartsController{

public PageReference selctedInvs() {
    if(transTypeWH || transTypeVH){

        String selectedInv=String.valueOf(apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('selInv'));
        Inventory__c invl;
        if(selectedInv != null){
            Invl=[select id,Name,Product__r.name,Total_Received__c,Warehouse__c,Warehouse_Location__c from Inventory__c where id=:selectedInv]; 
        }
        list<wrapTran> wraptranList =new list<wrapTran>();
        wrapInvList.add(new WrapInv(String.valueOf(invl.Product__r.name),wraptranList,0,Integer.valueOf(invl.Total_Received__c))); 
        system.debug('wrapInvList======'+wrapInvList);
    }
    else{
        ApexPages.Message myMsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Select Warehouse/Vehicle first');
        ApexPages.addMessage(myMsg);
    }
    return null;
}



public PageReference InvQtyChange() {

    String selectedInv=String.valueOf(apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('qtyPrd'));

    wrapTran temp;
    for(WrapInv serW : wrapInvList){  
        if(serW.PrdName == selectedInv){
            if(serW.Qty <= serW.AvailQty){
                serW.tranList.clear();

                for(integer m=0;m<serW.Qty;m++){

                     temp=new wrapTran(serW.PrdName,'',null);
                    serW.tranList.add(temp);
                }

            } 
            else{
                serW.Qty=0;
            }                                    
         }
    }
    return null;
} 


public class WrapInv{
   public list<wrapTran> tranList{get;set;}
   public Integer Qty{get;set;}
   public String PrdName{get;set;}
   public Integer AvailQty{get;set;}

   public WrapInv(String pname,List<wrapTran> LI,Integer sn,Integer avail){
       AvailQty=avail;
       PrdName=pname;
       tranList=LI;
       system.debug('translist========'+tranList);
       Qty=sn;
   }
```

Visualforce page:

```
 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapInvList}" var="invs">
              <apex:column headerValue="Product" value="{!invs.PrdName}"/>
              <apex:column headerValue="Recived Quantity" value="{!invs.AvailQty}"/>
              <apex:column headerValue="Quantity to Transfer" >
                        <apex:actionRegion ><apex:inputtext value="{!invs.Qty}">
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="invPrd" action="{!InvQtyChange}">
                                <apex:param name="qtyPrd" value="{!invs.PrdName}"/>
                            </apex:actionSupport>
                        </apex:inputtext></apex:actionRegion>
                    </apex:column>
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
    public class TrasferPartsControllerTest{

    static testMethod void myTest(){

    test.starttest();

    //perform required operation before this

    TrasferPartsController TP=new TrasferPartsController();
    TP.selctedInvs();
    TP.InvQtyChange();

    test.stoptest();
    }
}
```

Comment: You set the qty via code in your test method. Replicating what the user does on the page. Wrapinvlist[x].qty=xyz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set the required properties and page parameters expected by the controller in the test case. E.g.

```
@isTest
public class TrasferPartsControllerTest{

    static testMethod void myTest(){

        list<TrasferPartsController.WrapInv> wrapInvList = new list<TrasferPartsController.WrapInv>();
        // TODO: Complete WrapInv() constructor call with required params
        TrasferPartsController.WrapInv wrapI = new TrasferPartsController.WrapInv();
        wrapInvList.add(wrapI);

        TrasferPartsController TP = new TrasferPartsController();
        TP.wrapInvList = wrapInvList;

        system.currentPageReference().getParameters().put('qtyPrd', wrapInvList[0].PrdName);

        test.starttest();
        TP.InvQtyChange();
        test.stoptest();

        // TODO: Make some assertions about the expected changes to tranList and Qty
    } 
}
```